# Intel Rapid Storage HDD+msata

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, installation, msata

I have have a laptop with two hard disk's, one is HDD of 320 GB and a msata drive of 32 GB. Now I have Windows 10 installed directly in msata, and I want to swap for windows 8.1.

The situation is that I need to use this msata as cache, with intel rapid storage technology, but I don't know well what type of sata device I need to use.

Here some image from the bios

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HDXqJnZ.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OURIymx.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CMx76wg.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/z3aXUH7.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/KzokUK5.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1LkT1Sc.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OoPddTo.jpg]

How can I install the Operation System in HDD drive and use the msata with intel rapid storage as cache?

Comment: What model is that laptop?

Comment: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/How-it-Works-Intel-SSD-Caching-148/

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Intel Rapid Start is not same as Intel Rapid Storage. From screenshot looks like you don't have this option available (in SATA mode options there needs to be IDE, AHCI and Intel Smart Response Technology or something similar; you're missing last one).

You should go to the manufacturer's site (you don't say that, but I see you're on LG U460) and check if it has ISRT in addition to IRST.

Comment: Yes, there is a Intel Rapid Storage Drive, I just need to enable Intel Rapid Start in Bios, keep SATA mode in AHCI , install Windows 8.1 in HDD drive and then install the driver?

Comment: But you don't have the ISRT option in the BIOS. How do you know you have Intel Rapid Storage Drive? Rapid storage essentially creates RAID from HDD and mSATA SSD. It needs to be supported in BIOS. Is it?

Comment: The laptop come with Intel Rapid Storage with windows 8(not in bios), but then I installed windows 10 directly in msata.There is drive in the site of LG of intel rapid storage.

Comment: This is SATA/AHCI software driver for Windows. I'll repeat: you need to have ISRT present in BIOS anywhere to have Rapid Storage enabled. For example in my system it looks like this: http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/3534/6012.isrt_5F00_bios.jpg
But all you have is IRST. Make sure your BIOS supports ISRT on manufacturer's site.